# Identify a service

Tags: symfony

I'm using SensioLabsInsights to get reports on my application, and one of the violations does not give me a lot of info to correct it. Here is the screenshot :

[image: My error]

As you can see, I have to find the service that uses `DriverChain`, but I have no idea how to do it because the name is not very explicit.

Does someone have an idea on how I should do to find it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a private service created by a custom container extension. Since you have no idea from where this service could be defined, it will probably go away once you update your doctrine dependencies. Check out this issue: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/238

More info on private services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried a `composer update` but nothing changed... An other idea maybe ?